# Upgrade Flink API from 1.4 to 1.10

Tags: apache-flink

I have an application that uses Apache Flink 1.4 and now I want to upgrade it to Flink 1.10. Is there some guide to do that because it seems there are deprecated classes between the 2 versions like StandaloneClusterClient and I could not find information online on which class I should use in place of it.

Answer (score 2):

StandaloneClusterClient was removed by [FLINK-11540](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11540). If you look at https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/7659 you'll see an example of porting a test app to the new API.

BTW, you may find it helpful to review [the release notes for all the intervening releases](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/#release-notes). [API Migration Guides](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/migration.html) and [Upgrading Applications and Flink Versions](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/upgrading.html) are also relevant.